Android developers must be company officers?
The license agreement for Android SDK and Android Studio contains the following clause:

2.4 If you are agreeing to be bound by the License Agreement on behalf of your employer or other entity, you represent and warrant that you have full legal authority to bind your employer or such entity to the License Agreement. If you do not have the requisite authority, you may not accept the License Agreement or use the SDK on behalf of your employer or other entity.

I'm going to use "officer" as shorthand for "someone with the authority to bind a company to a legal contract/license".
By my reading of this license clause, an employee developer who is not an officer of their employer matches the "If you do not have the requisite authority" condition and therefore "may not... use the SDK" in the course of that employment, even if another individual who is an officer stands ready to execute the agreement (or may even have already done so).
Is that correct?  It seems contrary to the expected use of such tools.

I would guess that, from the first sentence in this clause, it applies to the case where a company employee is accepting the license, rather than the case where that license has already been accepted by the company. I would read the last sentence as implicitly saying "... or use the SDK on behalf of your employer or other entity without an agreement". It doesn't literally say that, but it's not much of a leap to say that if there already is an agreement (made by someone who is able to make such an agreement) for you to be allowed to use the SDK, then you can use the SDK.

@kaya3: Ahh, but Google isn't offering (at least, not publicly) the officer an agreement by which the other employees can use the SDK, they only offer this agreement by which the officer can use the SDK.  And clause 14.6 expressly prohibits transfer and delegation (of both rights and responsibilities).

@BenVoigt An officer accepts on behalf of the company. Corporations are their own legal entity, like a person. "You" can refer to both a natural person or a corporation.

@user71659: Yes, an officer accepts on behalf of the company.  But how does that help the other employees?  They still don't have "the requisite authority" and are forbidden from using the SDK.  They can't use the SDK under the license given to the company, because I assume that would require delegating the rights from the company to the developers, and delegation is prohibited by the license.

@BenVoigt Employees don't use the software as an individual, but are using the software as part of the corporate person, the same "you". When you buy something from a store, you aren't buying from the cashier personally, but from the corporation, where the cashier is an agent.

@user71659: Sure, but the license agreement anticipates and forbids that.  "you may not ... use the SDK on behalf of your employer or other entity"

@BenVoigt It does not. You completely changed the meaning of the sentence by discarding the first half. Read again: "If you do not have the requisite authority, you may not accept the License Agreement or use the SDK on behalf of your employer or other entity"

@user71659: That refers to the authority to enter into legal agreements on behalf of the company, which is limited to company officers.  AFAIK, even if an officer has entered into the exact same agreement, that still doesn't give ordinary employees the authority to also enter that agreement.  So the predicate of that sentence is in full force.

@user71659: To be clear, are you saying that a non-officer can use the SDK if an officer agrees to the SDK license?  Because what it says to me is that an officer can agree to the license and use the SDK but the use of the SDK cannot be transferred/delegated to any other employee.

@BenVoigt, the officer agrees to the license on behalf of the company. If the company then tells an employee to use that SDK as part of their job duties, that is not transferring or delegating anything. Technically, the employee does not even have to agree to the license, even if they have to go through the motions to get the software in an operational state.

@BartvanIngenSchenau: Wouldn't the employee's job duty then be "use the SDK on behalf of your employer"?  Hard to argue that is implicitly allowed when the license agreement explicitly addresses the scenario.

@BenVoigt, the difference lies in who decides that the employee can use the SDK. An officer of the employer or the employee themselves.

"which is limited to company officers": no it isn't. A company can delegate to its employees authority to enter into contracts on its behalf. Such a person may be called an "agent." For example, when you buy an airline ticket, you form a contract of carriage with the airline, yet the clerk at the ticket counter in the airport (assuming that's where you bought the ticket) is an employee of the airline, not an officer.  So the answer is "yes," if you define "officer" to mean "someone with the authority to bind a company to a legal contract/license," but that definition begs the question.

@phoog: That may be the answer, but it's surprising.  It's very common for employees to perform a contract that someone higher in the company has agreed to.  To continue your airline example, flight crew exercise authority and responsibility under the contract of carriage, but they weren't the ones who entered into that contract on behalf of the company.  For Google to rule out the prevailing business model is worth a question, IMO.  (And there's also the issue of "full legal authority" verbiage in the license, where agents generally have very limited authority)

@BenVoigt I don't see the relevance of flight crews. The point is that when a consumer enters into a contract with any service provider, the employee who concludes the contract with the consumer is almost always not a company officer. Agents may have limited authority, but they typically have full authority to bind consumers to the service contracts that they are selling. The Google terms do not say "full legal authority to bind your employer to any contract"; it only requires full legal authority to bind the employer to that contract.
